# Mock DriverManager.getconnection method for junit/mockito unit tests

Tags: java, junit, mockito

How can i mock the DriverManager.getconnection method. I am new to junit and mockito and learning the use of the same. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.my.config.project.dsexecutor.model.DSConfig;

public class dsexecutor {
    public JsonArray readTableDataAsJson(String sqlQuery, DSConfig dataConfig) throws SQLException {

        String host = dataConfig.getHost();
        String httpPath = dataConfig.getHttpPath();
        String accessToken = dataConfig.getAccessToken();
        String username = dataConfig.getUsername();
   
        String jdbcString = String.format(
                "jdbc:datatest://%s:443;EnableArrow=0;transportMode=http;ssl=1;httpPath=%s;AuthMech=3;UID=token;PWD=%s",
                host, httpPath, accessToken);

        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcString, username, accessToken);
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
            try (ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(sqlQuery)) {
                JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
                    ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
                    int numColumns = metaData.getColumnCount();
                    for (int i = 1; i <= numColumns; i++) {
                        String columnName = metaData.getColumnName(i);
                        String columnValue = resultSet.getString(i);
                        jsonObject.addProperty(columnName, columnValue);
                    }
                    jsonArray.add(jsonObject);
                }
                return jsonArray;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Do you have tests for the integration with the database already? If so, then what purpose does mocking the connection code serve? If you don't have tests that talk to the database, why not? You're going to have to write tests for that at some point.

Comment: @ndc85430 i am learning junit and mockito. i am exploring the usage

Comment: @User1515 if you mock that, you won't be able to use your DB. learning to mock should also contain understanding what (and why) to mock

Comment: @Stultuske i understand that, i want to check if i have no control and access to the DB. how would i write a unit test to test the code.

Comment: have your mock (when called) throw an Exception

Answer (score 1):

Create a class to wrap the static call.

```
public class ConnectionProvider {
  private final String jdbcString;
  ...
  public Connection getConnection() {
     return DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcString, username, accessToken);
  }
}
```

Then mock this class.